# Phaser create new children for a group

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've looked around the phaser docs, but I cannot find a way to add a new child to a phaser group. how do I create and add a new child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the function `create`  [link to the documentation normal group](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Group.html#create__anchor)
*([link to the documentation physics group](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group.html#create__anchor))*.

```
 this.group.create(...);
```